# Getting data from objects that collide

Tags: object, cocos2d-iphone, sharing, collision

I'm currently designing a game using Cocos2d.  There's no code yet, as I'm still developing my ideas.  But, I've run across a question I can't answer and want to know if I'm just missing something or what?  Here's what I'm currently thinking:

I am "dropping" multiple blocks from the top of the screen and they move down the screen in random directions.  They will eventually settle at the bottom of the screen and stack up one on top of the other.  Eventually, while falling,  some blocks are going to collide with others. When two blocks collide I want to test to see if certain characteristics of each block are equal (e.g. size, color, orientation, etc.).  Each block is it's own object, will handle it's own movement and collision detection, and will have accessor methods for size, color, orientation, etc.

Here's my question:

Am I correct in thinking that each block is a separate unit in itself and doesn't know anything about the other blocks?  Block A, for instance, collides with Block B and only knows that it collided with something, but doesn't know it was another block?  If this is so, then how do I do a proper comparison?  How do I tell which block has collided with which block and get access to each block's data and where do I do the comparison?  In the layer?

I'd love to be pointed in a decent direction here.  I'm not really sure if what I'm wanting to do is even doable?  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a physics engine that usually comes along with cocos2d- either [chipmunk](http://code.google.com/p/chipmunk-physics/) or [box2d](http://www.box2d.org/). The physics engines will take care of collisions for you, and if you implement collision callbacks then you can know when two objects hit each other. You can then check the characteristics of each object and react accordingly. [This tutorial](http://www.alexandre-gomes.com/articles/chipmunk/) on Chipmunk and cocos2d integration might be helpful.

Comment: Thanks, Carter.  I appreciate your help.  Will check out the tutorial.